# Is realm query order consistent?

Tags: database, realm

When querying a realm db without explicit ordering can I rely on a given order in the results? Is it insertion order? Primary key? Last updated? Example below:

```cs
var results = Realm.All<MyRecord>().Where(i => i.MyProp == "in the wild wild west");
foreach (var result in results)
{
  // do a thing with the record
}
```

I need a consistent order but I would rather not add overhead by "being explicit" with the order as this will add search overhead, so long as realm is consistent in its results (provided no change on the db) I am happy to work with a default order given by realm.

Comment: Adding a single property to guarantee ordering is a super tiny amount of data and won't really add any impactful amount of overhead vs guaranteeing the order you want.

Comment: Whilst I do agree with you for the most part, I am bulk inserting ~4m records, the overhead does become noticeable with this amount of data and it would be a shame to add this if realm can be relied upon, I'd really appreciate understanding if it is necessary

Comment: I would not rely on Realm 'natural ordering' for anything. More importantly if data is ever inserted or modified, that ordering goes out the window. So two things *List properties are guaranteed to preserve their order of insertion.* so you can bank on that. Part of the issue also stems from reading the data back in with no set ordering: *For performance reasons, Results insertion order is not guaranteed to be preserved*. Meaning that when you read in results, there's no guaranteed order unless you define it.

Comment: Cheers that makes things clear for me, I will opt for explicit ordering unfortunately this likely means query overhead for the dataset size I'm working with. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would not rely on Realm 'natural ordering' for anything. More importantly if data is ever inserted or modified, that ordering goes out the window.

So two things

> List properties are guaranteed to preserve their order of insertion.

so you can bank on that. Part of the issue also stems from reading the data back in with no set ordering:

> For performance reasons, Results insertion order is not guaranteed to
>   be preserved.

Meaning that when you read in results, there's no guaranteed order unless you define it.

Comment: Technically the order starts falling apart if you delete objects.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce That's a tad unclear. Which ordering? The 'natural ordering' the OP was referring to or something else? Should I update/clarify the answer? If so, can you expand on your meaning a bit so I can modify the answer?

Comment: Insertion order is retained until you delete an object from Realm, at which point the last item in the Realm (or some item, really) takes up its place and then suddenly you don't have insertion order anymore. But the default order really only changes on deletion.